# How to get different values of a variable

Tags: c#, string

I took the values ​​that are in the DB and put in a variable called type.

I want to get the values ​​that are after the space. example

```
type = "type1 type2 type3 type4";
```

I want to separate these values​​.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: Why does this have the `database` tag? It doesn't really matter where the values came from, anyway.

Comment: @Jashaszun: removed the "database" tag. However, there seems to be a serious design flaw in the database. You should **never** store multiple values in one field. He should normalize the table and store ach value in it's own field.

Comment: Who is closing this as not programming related? Have you gone bonkers? :-)

Comment: They're closing it because "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: Yes, a minimal understanding of the _problem,_ not the solution, and it suggests posting attempted solutions, which may number zero if you understand and elucidate the problem perfectly but have _no_ idea how to solve it. SO has always been for all levels of question, including (with apologies to OP) people who know very little.

Comment: @paxdiablo - Yes, SO has always been for programmers of different levels but the OP should show _some_ effort at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method without arguments:

```
string[] values = type.Split();
```

If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters.

Comment: Does that work? It doesn't appear to be a valid overload according to the net45 docs.

Comment: @paxdiablo what part is not valid?

Comment: @paxdiablo its valid syntax

Comment: @paxdiablo It's work perfectly, there is such overload for `Split()`.

Comment: I don't _know_ it's invalid, I'm asking. The docs have no zero-arg-count overload (unlike trim), the first is the char-array overload.

Comment: How not to think of that?
Thanks and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @paxdiablo there is `params` type of parameter, which means any number of chars. You can pass zero chars :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky lol you beat me to it,was goig to say that :)

Comment: Ah, forgive my oversight, I didn't even notice the "params" in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method:

```
string[] types = type.Split(' '); // [ "type1", "type2", "type3", "type4" ]
```

Comment: How not to think of that?
Thanks and excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method of the string type.

The Split method will split your string and return you back string array (string[]).

For example:

```
var type = "type1 type2 type3 type4";

string[] words = type.Split(' ');
```

By the way, you may want to consider using another name for your variable rather than `type`, since it's very similar to the Type class in .NET.